# Create object with key:value in one line

Tags: javascript, object

I need implement this in one line, if possible:

I have an object

```
var object1 = {};

object1['key_1'] = "value_1";
object1['key_2'] = "value_2";
object1['key_3'] = "value_3";
```

I need pass to an function one item from object (not only value ), key - only string value

```
for (var key in object1)
    FunctionTemp({key:object1[key]}); // - this don't work as I need, and eval() method I don't want
```

maybe there is something like this

```
FunctionTemp((new {})[key]=object1[key]) - its don't work!!! :)
```

Comment: How is `FunctionTemp` going to deal with its parameter? Maybe there is a simpler way of doing what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you really want it in one line you can do it like this:

```
var temp;
for (var key in object1)
    FunctionTemp(((temp = {}) && (temp[key] = object1[key]))? temp: null);
```

but I think it is no longer readable as it is, the most ideal solution would be to break it down into several lines.

```
var temp;
for (var key in object1) {
    temp = {};
    temp[key] = object1[key];
    FunctionTemp(temp);
}
```

Comment: hi man, thanx, you help me find out another my bad-code style - "var" declarations in loops :)....

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not possible without a function.

What you want to do is this:

```
var key = getKey(); //some means of determining a key dynamically
var val = getVal(); //some means of determining a value dynamically
var obj = {};
obj[key] = val;
this.doSomething(obj);
```

What you need is [another method](http://underscorejs.org/#object) that assembles the object based on the dynamic key/value.

```
this.doSomething(_.object([[getKey(), getVal()]]));
```